# Why do some of my files in visual studio get created as "Shortcuts"?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Why do some of my files in visual studio get created like this:

http://i.minus.com/jQi1qFTagyRVD.png

And why does it prevent me from moving them around? How am I supposed to work with a folder hierarchy in visual studio 2010 without this happening?

The main problem with this is that I cannot move files between folders using the solution explorer once I've added them. In order to move them I have to remove them, then drag them to a different folder, then add them again, this seems silly. See image:
http://i.minus.com/jlhGNHjyvpGOO.png

Answer (score 0):

Folder structure of VS solution does not have to map one-to-one to file locations. You can add files "as link" (small triangle on Add button when you adding existing item) to a folder in VS solution. Such files will not be copied to the disk folder you are adding to, but rather have "link" pointing to original location (using relative path). I'd recommend opening the solution file in text editor to see how different files are referenced.

I.e. this feature is useful when you want to share sources between different projects.

I'm not sure about "move them around" part...